# Remove all borders from my chart in angular-chart-js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, chart.js, angular-chart

I'm using [angular-chart-js](http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/) for my charts and I want to remove all the borders in my chart. The problem is only the first one is affected and not the rest.

**chart**

```
<canvas id="doughnut" class="chart chart-doughnut" chart-data="vm.data" chart-labels="vm.labels" chart-colors="vm.chart1Color" chart-dataset-override="override"></canvas>
```

**controller**

```
$scope.override = { borderWidth: [0, 0] };
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With angular-chart-js, you must use a chart.js version >= 2.x, so this is the way to remove borders:

**JS:**

```
$scope.options = { elements: { arc: { borderWidth: 0 } } };
```

**HTML**

```
<canvas ... chart-options="options"></canvas>
```

---

DEMO: <kbd>[PLUNKER](https://plnkr.co/edit/zBaRE6VskBeeWfdvr9bP?p=preview)</kbd>